# How to change style of single component onClick in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to build a to-do-list in react.

I have 2 components so far:

The first one handles the input:

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItems from './ListItems.js';

class InputComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            entries: []
        }

        this.getText = this.getText.bind(this);
    }

    getText() {
        if(this._inputField.value !== '') {
            let newItem = {
                text: this._inputField.value,
                index: Date.now()
            }

            this.setState((prevState) => {
                return {
                    entries: prevState.entries.concat(newItem)
                }
            })
            this._inputField.value = '';
            this._inputField.focus();

        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input ref={ (r) => this._inputField = r } >
                </input>
                <button onClick={ () => this.getText() }>Go</button>
                <div>
                    <ListItems 
                        entries={this.state.entries}   
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}

export default InputComponent;
```

The second one is about the actual entries in the list:

```
import React from 'react';

class ListItems extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.lineThrough = this.lineThrough.bind(this);
        this.listTasks = this.listTasks.bind(this);
    }

    lineThrough(item) {
        console.log(item);
        //item.style = {
        //    textDecoration: 'line-through'
        //}
    }

    listTasks(item) {
        return(
            <li key = { item.index }>
                <div 
                    ref = { (r) => this._itemText = r } 
                    style = {{
                        width: 50 + '%',
                        display: 'inline-block',
                        backgroundColor: 'teal',
                        color: 'white',
                        padding: 10 + 'px',
                        margin: 5 + 'px',
                        borderRadius: 5 + 'px'
                    }}
                >
                    { item.text }
                </div>
                <button onClick={ () => this.lineThrough(this._itemText) }>Done!</button>
                <button>Dismiss!</button>
            </li>
        )
    }

    render() {
        let items = this.props.entries;
        let listThem = items.map( this.listTasks );

        return(
            <ul style = {{
                listStyle: 'none'
            }}>
            <div>
                { listThem }
            </div>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default ListItems;
```

As you can see, i want to have two buttons for each entry, one for the text to be line-through, and one to delete the entry.

I am currently stuck at the point where i try to address a specific entry with the "Done!" button to line-through this entry's text.

I set a ref on the div containing the text i want to style and pass that ref to the onClick event handler.

Anyways, the ref seems to be overwritten each time i post a new entry...

Now, always the last of all entries is addressed. How can i properly address each one of the entries?
What would be the best practice to solve such a problem?

Comment: thats the problem if you want to manage multiple items within one component. Don´t do that. Create a component for one task. this way you do not have to mess around with those refs. In my opinion you almost NEVER need refs. If you need them (if you think you need them) you are doing (maybe) something wrong

Comment: So you are saying i should rather create a self containing component (dynamically) when posting a new to-do-item, instead of storing the parameters in the parents state as an array?

Comment: yes, definitely!

Answer (score 0):

you could pass an additional prop with index/key of the todo into every item of your todo list. With passing event object to your handler lineThrough() you can now get the related todo id from the attributes of your event target.

Kind regards

```
class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: []
    }
    this.done = this.done.bind(this);
  }

  done(id) {
    this.state.todos[id].done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.todos.map(t => <Todo item={t} onDone={this.done} />)
    );
  }
}

const Todo = ({item, onDone}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{item.title}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => onDone(item.id)}>done</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need map listItems then every list item get its own ref

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class ListItems extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.lineThrough = this.lineThrough.bind(this);
    }

    lineThrough(item) {
        item.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    }
    render() {

        return(
            <ul style = {{
                listStyle: 'none'
            }}>
            <div>
                    <li key={this.props.item.index}>
                        <div
                            ref={(r) => this._itemText = r}
                            style={{
                                width: 50 + '%',
                                display: 'inline-block',
                                backgroundColor: 'teal',
                                color: 'white',
                                padding: 10 + 'px',
                                margin: 5 + 'px',
                                borderRadius: 5 + 'px'
                            }}
                        >
                            {this.props.item.text}
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={() => this.lineThrough(this._itemText)}>Done!</button>
                        <button>Dismiss!</button>
                    </li>
            </div>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

class InputComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            entries: []
        }

        this.getText = this.getText.bind(this);
    }

    getText() {
        if(this._inputField.value !== '') {
            let newItem = {
                text: this._inputField.value,
                index: Date.now()
            }

            this.setState((prevState) => {
                return {
                    entries: prevState.entries.concat(newItem)
                }
            })
            this._inputField.value = '';
            this._inputField.focus();

        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input ref={ (r) => this._inputField = r } >
                </input>
                <button onClick={ () => this.getText() }>Go</button>
                <div>
                    {this.state.entries.map((item, index) => {
                        return <ListItems key={index} item={item} />
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}
```